# How do I update an Addon for 2.8

Tags: python, mesh, add-on

I have an Addon I'd like to use, but when I would install the .py file, theres a message on the far right saying I need to "upgrade to 2.8x...". The addon seems to be added into my Addons list, but when I search for it in Blender, it cannot be found.  Is there anything I can do to use this addon?

[image]

Comment: AFAIC questions asking to upgrade commercial addons should be off-topic on BSE.  [See the addon page.r](https://blendermarket.com/products/plating-generator)  It clearly mentions being upgraded for 2.8.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're comfortable reading and writing Python, you won't be able to do anything but wait for the addon creator to do it.

2.8 changed the API quite a bit, but this addon may or may not use the parts that changed. So updating the addon might be as easy as changing a few lines, or as difficult as a complete rewrite of several parts of the script.

Your best bet is to use it in 2.79 for now and link/append it in.