# Creating Cubes from a Spreadsheet/CSV file and export Object info

Tags: python, scripting, objects, export, import

Im recently joining Blender community, and I have a question that related to my work. Hope you guys can help me finding the answer. So my question has 2 parts:

1/ Is there a way that I can create multiple cubes with name and dimension from a spreadsheet or CSV file?

2/ After putting the cubes them in place, working and duplcating them. Can I export them back to spreadsheet with name and quantity that has used in the scene?

Comment: You should have simply searched this forum for csv and found answer like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/186766/111042).  It'll involve python scripting.

Comment: Hello, Mr. Brn, welcome. The answers to this particular question are 'Yes', and 'Yes'. and that is about as far as we can go, this time round. I suggest you have a look at the suggested duplicate answers, maybe get stuck, then come back and ask us how to get unstuck, showing us what you have tried. That would fit our format here, on Blender SE ..  it would give us something specific to  help you out with.